# Styled radio button, needs to link on click while maintaining style

Tags: html, css

I am using styled radio buttons as a simple nav for something. I just need to know how to have them link to something while maintaining the styles I applied.

In the code below, the 'Home' button is linking to something, but no longer has the properties of a radio button.

How can I keep the 'hover' and 'clicked' styles while having it link?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.navText {
font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 15px;
font-weight: 400;
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
color: white;
}
input[type=radio] {
display: none;
}
.overlay {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 100px;
height: 50px;
margin-left: 5px;
display: table;
background-color: grey;
}
input[type=radio]:hover + .overlay {
background-color: red;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + .overlay {
background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<label><input type="radio" name="nav"><a href="#"><span class="overlay"><h1 class="navText">Home</h1></span></a></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="nav"><span class="overlay"><h1 class="navText">Postings</h1></span></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="nav"><span class="overlay"><h1 class="navText">About</h1></span></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="nav"><span class="overlay"><h1 class="navText">Contact</h1></span></label>
<label><input type="radio" name="nav"><span class="overlay"><h1 class="navText">Other</h1></span></label>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using an anchor (`<a>`) tag, set the `input`'s `onclick` function to change the value of `document.location` to your desired URL:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="nav" onclick="document.location='#';">
    <span class="overlay">
        <h1 class="navText">Home</h1>
    </span>
</label>
```

See the following working jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/fry3gyp7/